# What does loopback health really check?

Tags: testing, loopbackjs, loopback, health-check

I added the component @loopback/health to my loopback4 server but I don't understand on what it's based to assume my server is up. I searched on https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Health.html#add-custom-live-and-ready-checks and on google but I can't find any infos about how it's working.

Thanks for your light !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without configuring any additional custom checks, `@loopback/health` only configures a Startup Check that keeps track when the REST server (which is a LifeCycleObserver) is started and shutdown. This is useful for infrastructure with existing tooling that consumes (e.g. Kubernetes, Cloud Foundry), or if the LoopBack 4 project does more beyond a REST server.

It is still an experimental package, and there are intentions to expand the scope to encompass other LifeCycleObservers of the LoopBack 4 app such as DataSources.